# Deny process of editing it's own memory?

Tags: stack, restore

Well, I'm working on a small project, and this may sounds stupid, but I want to keep a process from editing its own memory.

Is there something like VirtualProtect that can do this?

Comment: What would the process be able to do, if it was not able to modify any memory? Also, please specify the operating system(s) in which you want to do this.

Comment: Windows, I want it to only be able to read the specified section of memory, not write.

Comment: A process that can't change its own memory - what could it possibly achieve? It wouldn't be able to compute anything. Perhaps describe what you're trying to achieve (as an overall goal) in more detail.

Comment: Ah - so you're wanting to restrict it from writing to *some portion* of its own memory? What are the defining characteristics of this portion/region? Also, what language are you working in?

Comment: I'm working with C++/ASM, I'm patching a section, and it patch's it back... and I can't reverse that function because it's mega obfuscated. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: "it patches it back" - so you're attacking some *other* piece of software? That a) doesn't sound good, and b) doesn't sound like something to help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark memory in your own process as write protected.  See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366785(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx